# Simpler way to hide/show divs using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have five side buttons that drop to five specific "sub-menus". They're actually just divs. I am currently hiding/showing them with very basic jquery and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner, simpler way to handle all the hide/show calls? Thanks.

Here is a fiddle example of what I mean:https://jsfiddle.net/SteveSerrano/b562v654/

HTML:

```
<!-- TOP MENU IS NOT HIDDEN UNTIL ANOTHER IS CLICKED -->
<button id="nyNavButton">NEW YORK</button>
<div id="nyContainer">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>PHP generated links...</li>
      <li>PHP generated links...</li>
      <li>PHP generated links...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="njNavButton">NEW JERSEY</button>
<div id="njContainer">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>PHP generated links...</li>
      <li>PHP generated links...</li>
      <li>PHP generated links...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="nhNavButton">NEW HAMPSHIRE</button>
<div id="nhContainer">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>PHP generated links...</li>
      <li>PHP generated links...</li>
      <li>PHP generated links...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#njContainer").hide();
$("#nhContainer").hide();

$("#njNavButton").click(function(){
    $("#njContainer").show();
    $("#nyContainer").hide();
    $("#nhContainer").hide();
    });

$("#nhNavButton").click(function(){
    $("#nhContainer").show();
    $("#nyContainer").hide();
    $("#njContainer").hide();
    });

$("#nyNavButton").click(function(){
    $("#nyContainer").show();
    $("#njContainer").hide();
    $("#nhContainer").hide();
    });
```

Comment: If this code works, it would be more appropriate for [**CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ***but check their [guidelines](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) first***

Comment: Had no idea this existed. Thanks.

Comment: Use `not()` to select all but the desired element. You can combine them into one handler then.

Comment: Tada -> https://jsfiddle.net/b562v654/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not()` to select all but the desired element. You can combine them into one handler then.

e.g.

```
$("#njContainer").hide();
$("#nhContainer").hide();

$(".button").click(function() {
  $('.container').not($(this).next('.container').show()).hide();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/b562v654/3/

### Notes:

- I added classes to the button and container elements (instead of managing all the unique IDs).
- This code assumes your containers follow your buttons in the DOM. if that changes you will need to change the `.next('.container')`

Comment: All my class names are different anyway, but thank you very much for this solution. It works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("#njContainer").hide();
$("#nhContainer").hide();

$("button").click(function(){
    $("div[id*=Container]").each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    })
    $(this).next().show()
    })
```

Hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

Add class 'linkButton' to your buttons and 'linkContainer' to your containing div's:

```
  $("#njContainer").hide();
   $("#nhContainer").hide();

  $(".linkButton").click(function(){
    $(".linkContainer").hide();
    $(this).next(".linkContainer").show();

})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ardieziff/b562v654/4/